# Read user input into global string C#

Tags: c#, class, input, global

I'm reading files into DataTables but need to use different file names for different version of my product. How can I get the product version number as entered by a user set as a global variable in a class?

I want to apply a case statement to the "using (TextFieldParser)" line so it will use the correct files for the correct versions.

```
static public DataTable VolumeImport()
{
    DataTable Volumes = new DataTable();
    Volumes.Columns.Add("MediaId", typeof(string));
    Volumes.Columns.Add("MediaTypeName", typeof(string));
    Volumes.Columns.Add("MediaGroupName", typeof(string));
    Volumes.Columns.Add("Barcode", typeof(string));
    Volumes.Columns.Add("PoolName", typeof(string));

    using (TextFieldParser volumes = new TextFieldParser("C:\\Input Files\\752.dat"))

    {
        volumes.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
        volumes.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
        volumes.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
        volumes.TrimWhiteSpace = true;


        string[] deviceprops;

        while (!volumes.EndOfData)
        {
            deviceprops = volumes.ReadFields();
            Volumes.Rows.Add((deviceprops[3]).Replace("'", String.Empty), (deviceprops[7]).Replace("'", String.Empty), (deviceprops[8]).Replace("'", String.Empty),
            (deviceprops[16]).Replace("'", String.Empty), (deviceprops[50]).Replace("'", String.Empty));
        }
    }
    return Volumes;
}
```

I've add the following but it doesn't ever ask for the version. I suspect this is because its not part of the void Main

```
public class Version
{
    public string nbuversion { get; set; }

    public void GetVersion()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Version:"); // Prompt for version
        string nbuversion = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Update: I've managed to solve this problem based on the advise below. Thanks a lot.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Data;

public class DataCollect
{
    static public Dictionary<int, string> Day_Lookup = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    public string nbuversion { get; set; }
    public string filename { get; set; }

    class NBUXMLWriter
    {
        static public void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DataCollect s = new DataCollect();
            s.GetVersion();
            s.SetFileLocations();
            s.DayImport();
        }
    }
    public void GetVersion()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Version:");
        nbuversion = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void SetFileLocations()
    {
        switch (nbuversion)
        {
            case "7.6":
                filename = "input1.txt";
                break;
            case "7.7":
                filename = "input2.txt";
                break;
        }
    }

    public void DayImport()
    {

        string filepath = "C:\\Input Files\\Static\\";

        using (TextFieldParser daysofweek = new TextFieldParser((filepath)+(filename)))

        {
            daysofweek.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            daysofweek.Delimiters = new string[] { " " };
            daysofweek.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
            daysofweek.TrimWhiteSpace = true;


            string[] dayprops;

            while (!daysofweek.EndOfData)
            {
                dayprops = daysofweek.ReadFields();
                int daynumber;
                bool daynumberparsed = Int32.TryParse((dayprops[0]), out daynumber);
                string dayname = dayprops[1];
                Day_Lookup.Add((daynumber), (dayname));
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Day is" + Day_Lookup[(4)]);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Comment: where you created the object for the class `Version` and where is the method call `GetVersion()`

Comment: "I suspect this is because its not part of the void Main". hmm. never heard that all console actions should be part of the Main method. Is your GetVersion() method referenced anywhere? Does it actually get called/executed? Is your application actually compiled to a console application? Many possibilities here. Time to do some debugging...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this will ReadLine into local variable within the `GetVersion()` method:

```
public void GetVersion()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the Version:"); 
    string nbuversion = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Do this will write to Version.nbuversion property:

```
public string nbuversion { get; set; } //readline into "Global" property here
public void GetVersion()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the Version:"); 
    nbuversion = Console.ReadLine(); //remove "string"
}
```

This sample code should be enough to get you started

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Version v = new Version();
            v.GetVersion();

            //do stuff with nbuversion - 1st way
            Console.WriteLine("1:" + v.nbuversion);

            //do stuff with nbuversion - 2nd way
            v.VolumeImport();
        }
    }

    public class Version
    {
        public string nbuversion { get; set; }

        public void  GetVersion()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Version:");
            //string nbuversion = Console.ReadLine(); <- this will Readline into local variable - WRONG
            nbuversion = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public DataTable VolumeImport()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2:" + nbuversion);
            //do stuff with nbuversion
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is perfect and it allowed me to figure out how to pass the variables from one to the other class. I'll add the what I came with in the original post if possible